# Swipe down from navigation bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a React Native app that has a stack navigator nested in a drawer navigator using react-navigation. I am working on the screen shown below.

[image]

I'd like to be able to swipe down from the navigation bar and display a search menu.  I've placed the down arrow there using absolute positioning and added a pan responder to it, but the pan responder is not detecting anything.

What's the best way to detect a swipe down action on the navigation bar?

Edit: As requested here is the code of what I've already tried:
AppContainer.js:

```
export const MainNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
{
    ScreensStack: {screen: ScreensStack},
},
{
    drawerWidth: 235,
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    contentComponent: (props) => (
        <Drawer
            navigation = {props.navigation}
        />
    ),
}
```

);

```
export default class AppContainer extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <View style = {{flex: 1}}>
            <SlideDownMenuHandle2 />
            <MainNavigator />
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

SlideDownMenuHandle2:

export default class SlideDownMenuHandle2 extends React.Component {

```
render() {
    return (
        <Image
            style = {slideDownMenuStyles2.image}
            source = {Navigation.NAVIGATION_IMAGES.DOWN_ARROW_ICON_ORANGE}
        /> 
    );
}


componentWillMount() {
    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create(
        {
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => {console.log('onStartShouldSetPanResponder'); return true;},

            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => {console.log('onMoveShouldSetPanResponder'); return true;},

            onPanResponderMove: this.handlePanResponderMove.bind(this),
            onPanResponderRelease: this.handlePanResponderEnd.bind(this),
            onPanResponderTerminate: this.handlePanResponderEnd.bind(this),
            onPanResponderStart: this.handlePanResponderStart.bind(this),
        }
    );
}


handlePanResponderStart(e, gestureState) {
    console.log('START');
}


handlePanResponderMove(e, gestureState) {
    console.log('MOVE');
}


handlePanResponderEnd(e, gestureState) {
    console.log('END');
}
```

}

Comment: Please add [mcve] to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: side note, I'd not reccomend this from a ux perspective because both android and ios would open notifications instead if the user started the swipe from just a bit too high. This might breed user frustration if they frequently get the wrong action.